# I have a problem drawing an image in a canvas, when I write the code there is an error

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document .addEventListener ('keydown', function(evento){

if(evento .keyCode == 32){
console.log("salta");
}
});

var imgCubito,  imgTri, imgColorcafe;

 function cargaImagenes() {
  imgCubito = new Image();
  imgCubito.src = "img/Cubito.png";

}

var ancho =700;
var alto =300;
var canvas,ctx;

function inicializa() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
}

function borrarCanavas() {
  canvas.width = ancho;
  canvas.height = alto;
}

function dibujaCubito(){
  ctx.drawImage(imgCubito,0,0,192,192,100,100,50,50); //Line 31
}

//Bucle chido :v
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var FPS = 10;
setInterval(function(){
  principal(); // Line 38
},1000/10);



function principal(){
  borrarCanavas();
  dibujaCubito(); //line 45

}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="juego.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="inicializa();">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="300" style="border:2px solid #000000;"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the code Im using, and this is the mistake:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
at dibujaCubito (juego.js:31) ctx.drawImage(imgCubito,0,0,192,192,100,100,50,50);
at principal (juego.js:45) dibujaCubito(); Line 45
at juego.js:38   principal();

The error came when I wanted to draw the IMG, Im using JS and HTML

Comment: https://w3schools.invisionzone.com/topic/55213-failed-to-execute-drawimage-on-canvasrenderingcontext2d/

Comment: Your code looks correct, just make sure that the folder img is in the same folder as your JavaScript program.

Comment: @NO_GUI have already added the img to the folder, I also try to add the IMG from the Internet but the mistake still appearing

Comment: you forgot to call `cargaImagenes` function, to initialize image, your image is `undefined` now

Comment: @Montecamo I dont understand